# How to run query multiple times with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in SQL Server Studio,

I have a query with one variable and that variable is used multiple times in the query, in subqueries that are joined together; I get correct results.

I manually run the query 10 times, manually changing the variable each time, to get the 10 sets of results. I don't know how to have it be one query that gives me the 10 sets of results, running it 10 times--once each with each of the 10 variable values.

I can easily generate the list of the 10 variable values with a simple query.

I've not been successful in searching for an answer because I'm obviously not using the right search terms to narrow down the results to what I want to do.

I don't need to code this into an app, I just want to see the 10 sets of results by running the query once instead of running it 10 times, changing the variable each time.

Below is the query I am running 10 times, each time with a different value for the variable @cid.  If I knew how to articulate the following problem I'd probably know what to do, but here goes:

I can't simply replace `contentID = @cid` with `contentID in (101, 102, 103, 104, 105)` because... then the results are wrong for each contentID.  I hope this makes sense to someone!  Thanks

```
declare @cid int = 101

select
  b.userID,
  b.numComplete
from (
    select
      userID
    from contentTrackings
    where contentID = @cid
      and complete = 1
) as a
join (
    select
      userID,
      count(userID) as numComplete
    from contentTrackings
    where contentID in (
        select contentID
        from curriculums
        where curriculumID = @cid
      )
      and complete = 1
      and companyID = (
        select distinct companyID
        from curriculums
        where curriculumID = @cid
      )
    group by
      userID
    having count(userID) < (
        select count(contentID)
        from curriculums
        where curriculumID = @cid
    )
) as b on a.userID = b.userID
order by
  numComplete desc,
  userID
```

Comment: create a table holding only the values you need to change in the variable. Convert the current query into a function, the variable is the parameter. Call select newFunction(col) from newTable. You might need to add a new column to the function, because yuo cant use order by

Comment: Basic whitespace and formatting would help massively with readability

Comment: Another option is to group also by the `contentID` value, and use `WHERE ContentID IN (...)`

Comment: Thank you! I will try to wrap my head around these.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this?:

```
-- Only for test

CREATE TABLE contentTrackings (userID int, contentID int, companyID int, complete bit);
CREATE TABLE curriculums (curriculumID int, userID int, contentID int, companyID int);
INSERT INTO contentTrackings (userID, contentID, companyID, complete) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1),(2, 2, 2, 1),(3, 3, 3, 1),(4, 4, 4, 1),(5, 5, 5, 1),(6, 6, 6, 1),(7, 7, 7, 1),(8, 8, 8, 1),(9, 9, 9, 1),(10, 10, 10, 1);
INSERT INTO curriculums (curriculumID, userID, contentID, companyID) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1),(2, 2, 2, 2),(3, 3, 3, 3),(4, 4, 4, 4),(5, 5, 5, 5),(6, 6, 6, 6),(7, 7, 7, 7),(8, 8, 8, 8),(9, 9, 9, 9),(10, 10, 10, 10);

-- ------------------------

DECLARE @cids TABLE (idx int IDENTITY(1,1), cid int);
-- You can add values here
INSERT INTO @cids (cid) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
-- Result table
DECLARE @results TABLE (userID int, numComplete int);

DECLARE @i int;
DECLARE @cid int;
DECLARE @numrows int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @cids);
SET @i = 1;
IF @numrows > 0
WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @cids))
BEGIN
    SET @cid = (SELECT cid FROM @cids WHERE idx = @i);
    INSERT INTO @results
    SELECT 
      B.userID, 
      B.numComplete 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          userID 
        FROM 
          contentTrackings 
        WHERE 
          contentID = @cid 
          and complete = 1
      ) AS A
      JOIN (
        SELECT 
          userID, 
          COUNT(userID) as numComplete 
        FROM 
          contentTrackings 
        WHERE 
          contentID in (
            SELECT 
              contentID 
            FROM 
              curriculums 
            WHERE 
              curriculumID = @cid
          ) 
          AND complete = 1 
          AND companyID =(
            SELECT 
              DISTINCT companyID 
            FROM 
              curriculums 
            WHERE 
              curriculumID = @cid
          ) 
        GROUP by 
          userID 
        HAVING 
          COUNT(userID) < (
            SELECT 
              COUNT(contentID) 
            FROM 
              curriculums 
            WHERE 
              curriculumID = @cid
          )
      ) as B on A.userID = B.userID;
    SET @i = @i + 1;
END

-- Results
SELECT * FROM @cids
ORDER BY
  numComplete DESC,
  userID;
```

You can create an Stored Procedure/Function with this code.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to wrap my head around this.